# Issue with adding elements to array in Redux in React application using loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I and new to react and I and facing issue while adding multiple elements in redux array.
I and able to add elements in redux array but when adding second and subsequent elements, it modifies attributes of other elements in the array as well as other similar objects in redux store.

Below is my redux (reducer) code for adding elements to array:

```
switch (action.type) {
case ADD_DATA:
    return {
      ...state,
      arrayData: [...state.arrayData, action.payload],
    };
```

Below is react code for adding elements to array

```
dateArray.forEach((date) => {
     let currentData = someData;
     currentData ["attr1"] = "Day";
     currentData ["startDate"] = date;
     currentData ["endDate"] = date;
     dispatch(addData(currentData));
     console.log("Item:"+ currentData);
});
```

First element is adding correctly here. When second element is added in redux, first elements as well as some other similar objects in redux is also updated for attributes which is added to someData object (attr1, startDate, endDate). In console log I am getting correct data. Action code is not added here as I think it's not required at this point.

Could you please help in get rid of this issue as I don't want to update others but to add a fresh element to the array in redux.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try `let currentData = {...someData};`

Comment: Yes @HMR, I tried above solution and it worked like a charm:). Thank you so much for your help as you saved my day.
Could you please elaborate your answer as it would be helpful in future.

Comment: Neve mutate state, always create a [new state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

Comment: Thank you @HMR.
Why its a downvote? Have I asked anything wrong here?

Comment: Not my downvote, there is always some random person that will downvote without telling you why.